# How to position subview below left bottom corner of a button in view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an options button (that 3 vertical dotted button) on top of the view controller.
When I click that button, A list view should appear like in many other apps like WhatsApp...
I really don't know how to position it always near to the button programmatically.

Comment: You can add a custom view when clicking on that button

Answer (score 0):

Placing at the left-bottom of an existing view is quite easier:

```
func placeSubView(existingView: UIView)
{
    let desiredWidth = CGFloat(50.0)
    let desiredHeight = CGFloat(35.0)
    let (x, y) = (existingView.frame.origin.x - desiredWidth, existingView.frame.origin.y + existingView.frame.size.height)

    let desiredView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: desiredWidth, height: desiredHeight))

    existingView.superview?.addSubview(desiredView)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In case you are looking for popupo menu like view, you should search about [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller).

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040329/1506363).

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and make PopoverViewController a table view controller if you want a list.

```
@IBAction func displayPopover(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverViewController")
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.barButtonItem = sender
    present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```