# How to make actionsheet pop over a bar button on iPhone

Tags: swift

I know how to make an action sheet pop over a button on iPad but not for iPhone. it seems that on iphone the action sheet doesn't have popoverPresentationController:

```
    @IBAction func addChannel(_ sender: Any) {
        let sender = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let addChanel = UIAlertAction(title: "Add a Channel", style: .default) { (_) in
            self.addChannel()
        }
        let addContact = UIAlertAction(title: "Add a Contact", style: .default){ _ in
            
            self.addContact()
        }
        actionSheet.addAction(addChanel)
        actionSheet.addAction(addContact)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
//        actionSheet.popoverPresentationControlle
        if let popover = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController{
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
            actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down
        }
        
        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true)
        

    }
```

I want the action sheet pop over a button just like what WeChat + button does. Other stackoverflow answers are too old and not workable
Any idea is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44040329/4304998)

You cannot use UIAlertController as a popover on iPhones. One of alternatives is using a UITableView or something inside new UIViewController, which you can create like described below (Swift 5.0).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet private weak var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonAction() {
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let ppc = vc.popoverPresentationController
    ppc?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    ppc?.delegate = self
    ppc?.sourceView = button
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
}
```

Also, `popoverPresentationController` has property called `barButtonItem` which you can assign to your nav bar button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This methods adds a new viewcontoller over the viewcontroller and what I want is just a UIAlertController poping over the viewcontroller

Comment: You cannot do this on iPhones, UIAlertController is not meant to be a popover on these devices. One of alternatives is using a UITableView or something inside new UIViewController.

Comment: Ok, can you make this point clear in your answer so that more people can know this and I will accept your answer then